# How to know that my spark streaming query don't have any new kafka record to consume?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am starting a spark structured streaming query as follows:

```
val strquery = tempDataFrame2.writeStream.outputMode("append").queryName("table").format("console").start()
```

But I don't know what other parameters to use in this statement so that spark knows that there is no kafka records to consume and immediately stop the streaming?

Comment: How do you define  "there is no kafka records to consume"?

Comment: It is guaranteed as I have control over the kafka producer and I make sure that nothing gets published after a configured period.